# Google Sheets formula only showing some duplicates, not all of them

Tags: duplicates

I have a custom formula in my Google Sheet to find any duplicates in column A;(reference numbers)

=countif(A:A,A3)>1

I've also tried =COUNTIF($A$3:$A,A3)>1

The range is A3:A2199 as there are headers in rows 1 & 2

The formula however does not seem to pick up all the duplicated reference numbers, only some of them.

Is it possible to show me where i'm going wrong?

Many thanks,

Cat

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give you all duplicates

```
=sort(unique(filter(A3:A2199, COUNTIF(A3:A2199, A3:A2199)>1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks so much for this this. I've entered the formula but it unfortunately now gives zero duplicates. I'm not sure why?

Comment: I have added a screenshot! Share your spreadsheet if necessary.

Comment: Hi Mike, I see how the formula works now. Is it possible to have a formula that just changes the colour of the duplicate entries, to red for example? This is how my previous formula worked, although it was only picking up some, not all of them.

Comment: Build conditional formatting with `=countif(A:A,A3)>1` applied to A3 and below

Comment: Thanks Mike, that's the formula I was using, but it only seems to find some of the duplicates, not all of them. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: I don't understand since in my example all duplicates are displayed. Can you share a spreadsheet with example (limited to one column and if possible anonymized)